# Selecting rows in csv file in with the variable number of columns

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that i need to select certain rows. For me is easy remove the AGE and MEAN WEIGHT because these names are the same in any file.

`ID,AGE,HEIGHT,MEAN WEIGHT,20-Nov-2002,05-Mar-2003,09-Apr-2003,23-Jul-2003
1,23,1.80,80,78,78,82,82
2,25,1.60,58,56,60,60,56
3,20,1.90,100,98,102,98,102`

`ID,HEIGHT,20-Nov-2002,05-Mar-2003,09-Apr-2003,23-Jul-2003
1,1.80,78,78,82,82
2,1.60,56,60,60,56
3,1.90,98,102,98,102`

i have this code

```
import csv
out= open("C:/Users/Pedro/data.csv") 
rdr= csv.reader(out)
result= open('C:/Users/Pedro/datanew.csv','w')
wtr= csv.writer ( result,delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
for row in rdr:
    wtr.writerow( (row[0], row[2], row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7]) )
out.close()
result.close()
```

but my difficulty is select all columns that have dates. The number of columns of the dates may be variable. The solution could be to detect the character - in row[4]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100 % sure what's you're asking, but here is a script that may do what you want, which is to reproduce the file with all of an unknown number of date columns, plus your columns 0 and 2 (`ID` & `HEIGHT`):

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as infile:  # Use 'with' to close files automatically
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    headers = reader.next()  # Read first line

    # Figure out which columns have '-' in them (assume these are dates)
    date_columns = [col for col, header in enumerate(headers) if '-' in header]

    # Add our desired other columns
    all_columns = [0, 2] + date_columns

    with open('new.csv', 'w') as outfile:

        writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')

        # print headers
        writer.writerow([headers[i] for i in all_columns])

        # print data
        for row in reader:  # Read remaining data from our input CSV
            writer.writerow([row[i] for i in all_columns])
```

Does that help?

Comment: Great. Thank you for help me ;)

Comment: You're welcome, my pleasure. Please remember to accept answers that solve your problems, so the question is removed from the 'unanswered' page.